# How to clear search API textfield after each search

Tags: 8, forms, search

I am using Drupal 8 with the Search API module. Everything works as expected but the search terms remains in the search textfield after every search. This makes using the search function a bad user experience since the user needs to clear the text before entering their new terms.

I would like to the search textfield clear itself after every search but haven't figured out a way to do so. So far I have tried using hook_form_alter but can't seem to alter the input. Here is my code:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {
    if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-search-content-page-1') {
      $form['keys']['#default_value'] = '';
      // $form['keys']['#value'] = ''; also tried this but it didn't work
    }
  }
}
```

Clearing the default value didn't work. I also tried setting the value to an empty string as well but that totally killed search from working altogether. I feel that I am overlooking something really simple. Any suggestions?

Comment: Google doesn’t do this. What makes it bad UX? Are users complaining? Did you add a reset button to the view?

Comment: Just because Google doesn't do it, doesn't mean it is right. Use cases vary - so what works in one instance will not be the best solution in another. Also adding a reset button is not good UX design either.